# Public version control systems (e.g. Github, SVN) as file backup/cloud storage?

Tags: backup, git, svn, cloud-storage

I have personal laptop on which I am doing my study works and personal projects and hence, some directories contain very valuable content for me like: 1) OpenOffice documents; 2) source code files, 3) pdf/djuv books and articles (some of these files can be even 50 MB large, some of these files are very valuable and were costly to purchase). Hence some of my valuable directories are even 10 GB in size.

I would like to backup those special directories on the cloud to keep them as backups in case my laptop is stolen or lost. I like the Github/SVN approach very well - when I can control when and how I can commit new content to the server. I certainly do not like automatic synchronization, I need only backups from my computer to the server.

So - is it good idea to use some commercial SVN of Git provider as cloud storage/backup for some of my directories? As far as I have heard, then Git does not like large repositories, Git limits the size of repository to be under 1GB. But I would like to have repository for each of my top level directory and the size of such directory can be 10-20 GB.

Is it good idea to search for more friendly commercial GIT/SVN provider or my backup task should be performed with dedicated cloud storage solutions?

Comment: Version control systems are for text documents which change. If you can't do `diff` or `merge` on it, it doesn't belong in a version control system. So go ahead and put your source code files in a repository. Use something else for the pdf/djuv books and articles. These are not going to change, just copying them somewhere (`rsync`) should be enough.

Comment: I like the 'commit' functionality and integration with Windows Explorer very much in systems like SVN.

Comment: Then don't come complaining like [this guy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404458/version-control-system/404462#404462) when it doesn't work for your 20 GB ...